# Java. IO. StringBufferInputStream почему зачеркнут?

Tags: java, io

У меня класс StringBufferInputStream почему-то в среде разработки зачеркнутый, я так понимаю с намеком на то что он устарел, и его использовать опасно.

Вопрос: это у меня глюк, или на самом деле так и есть? Если да то какая альтернатива? Что-то я нигде не нашел инфы что он опасен может кто знает?

Comment: Посмотрите парочку первых ссылок из выдачи любого поисковика по названию класса и слову `deprecated` – там будет вся интересующая Вас информация.

Comment: `depreceted`, если кто не в курсе, это `устаревший`. Придумали что-то новое гораздо лучшее, а это объявили устаревшим и возможно когда-нибудь избавятся от него совсем. Часто в javadoc имеется рекомендация что использовать вместо устаревшего метода/класса и пр.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно это обозначает что класс или метод помечен как Depreacted.
А причина должна быть описана в соответствующей документации.
На что следует заменить зачёркнутое - довольно часто пишется прямым текстом в warnings (при включённых предупреждениях).